# Applying equivalent of image.expression function to imageCollection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm just starting to work with Google Earth Engine and I'm trying to calculate a simple index based on an expression. I found this image.expression function, but can't figure out what is the equivalent for an imageCollection.

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 10));
    
var image = ee.Image(s2.first())

// **HOW DO I DO THIS TO AN IMAGE COLLECTION, INSTEAD OF JUST THE SINGLE IMAGE**? 
var index= image.expression(
    '(1-((B6*B7*B8A)/B4)**0.5)*((B12-B8A)/((B12+B8A)**0.5)+1)', {
      'B4': image.select('B4'),
      'B6': image.select('B6'),
      'B7': image.select('B7'),
      'B8A': image.select('B8A'),
      'B12': image.select('B12')
});

Map.addLayer(index, {min: 0, max: 0.99, palette: ['FF0000', '00FF00']});
```

Answer (score 5):

**Whenever** you know how to transform a single image and you want to do it to every image in a collection, use `ImageCollection.map()`:

```js
var s2_index = s2.map(function (image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(1-((B6*B7*B8A)/B4)**0.5)*((B12-B8A)/((B12+B8A)**0.5)+1)', {
      'B4': image.select('B4'),
      'B6': image.select('B6'),
      'B7': image.select('B7'),
      'B8A': image.select('B8A'),
      'B12': image.select('B12')
  });
});

// s2_index is an ImageCollection
```